# In VBA, is there any way to copy an Excel range to PowerPoint without disturbing the global clipboard?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to run an automated process that creates a fairly large number of PowerPoint files using an Excel template to generate the required tables and charts, which are pasted into PowerPoint as images.

The process takes quite a while and I want to be able to do other things while it is running so I am trying to avoid using cut paste so the clipboard can be used for other things while the process is running. If I use cut and paste in the VBA code the global clipboard doesn't work while it is running.

I managed to avoid using the clipboard for charts by exporting the charts to bitmap files. However for there doesn't seem to be such a method for ranges of cells. Is there a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out. It uses the "Camera" tool which is almost invisible in Excel these days.

There's an empty chart on sheet1, and it contains a linked picture (see `SetUpChart` to add the picture).

Changing the picture's Formula changes its linked image. This process doesn't seem to impact the clipboard.

Note if the sheet with the chart isn't active when this runs, you'll get the wrong output.

```
'Test the export
Sub ExportSomeRanges()
    ExportRangeNoCopy Sheet1.Range("B11:D24"), "c:\Temp\test.png"
    ExportRangeNoCopy Sheet1.Range("B5:C8"), "c:\Temp\test2.png"
    ExportRangeNoCopy Sheet2.Range("C8:K13"), "c:\Temp\test3.png"
End Sub

'the sheet with the chart container needs to be active...
Sub ExportRangeNoCopy(rng As Range, fName As String)
   With Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
        'size the chart
        .Height = rng.Height
        .Width = rng.Width
        With .Chart.Shapes(1)
            'size the picture and set the source range
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 0
            'change the link to the source range
            .DrawingObject.Formula = "'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & _
                                       rng.Address(True, True)
            .Width = rng.Width
            .Height = rng.Height
        End With
        DoEvents
        .Chart.Export fileName:=fName, FilterName:="png"
   End With
End Sub


'Set up a chart with a linked picture object (one-time task)
'could not figure out how to do this manually.  Cribbed from:
'https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/5405-solved-camera-tool-how-to-use-it-in-code/
Sub SetUpChart()
 Dim rngcolor
 Set rngcolor = Range("B5:C8")
 rngcolor.Copy
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Select
 With ActiveChart.Pictures.Paste
 .Formula = "=" & rngcolor.Address()
 End With
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This is good solution but not quite what I want. After playing around with it, I realized that when I paste from excel a power point table object is created on the slide not just an image. I suspect that with using the clipboard you would need to created the table from scratch in VBA and copy all the individual cell formats and values  over. Will leave this question open a bit longer to see if get any more insights, but failing that will accept your answer as I suspect its the nearest thing to a simple solution that I am going to find.